# <ng-src> display broken img on ie 10

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

`<ng-src>` display as broken image on ie 10

actually i noticed that if i open the url of the img

the image display with error img also ,

FYI : img url is correct and working fine on all browser

is there a solution for this is